router. function doesn't execute after auth middleware
router.get('/', auth, function(req, res){
    funcs.getBalance(req.params.user, function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({error: err.message});
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(result[0]);
        }
    })
});

Here we have a route. Notice the auth middleware. It checks if the user has an valid web token. The problem is that the router.get function doesn't execute anything after auth has been executed
function auth(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.cookies.token;

    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({message: "No token"});
    }

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_TOKEN, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(401).json({message: "Invalid token"});
        }

        req.user = decoded;

        return res.status(200).json({message: "Authentication ok"});
    });
}

I've tried small tweaks to the code but I honestly don't know why everything stops after auth function.
I'm new to api development and javascript in general so the problem could be something small and simple that I don't have the eyes to notice  yet.

You never call next

Thank you, it works now. I added next().
